# Simple PHP Query

Tags: php

Does the following condition checks value at one of array's memory location identified by key `$propertyName` or does it check if a key name is equal to `$value`?

```
      if($this->_properties[$propertyName] !=$value ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks whether `$this->_properties[$propertyName]` is not equal to `$value`.  Specifically, it uses `$propertyName` to perform a key lookup in the associative array `$this->_properties` and extract its value, and then compares that to `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

It checks the value. It's not an array in this case, but a hashtable.

Comment: can u pls elaborate on the hashtable concept. I am new to PHP and just clearing my basics OOPS concept "classes".

Comment: A hashtable is a key-value form of an array. A normal array is simply a list of objects. In a hashtable, each of these objects also has a name. When you use $arr[notanumber] it's a hashtable.

Comment: Yep. I didn't know how it was called in PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the value in the map `$this->_properties` that corresponds to the key name `$propertyName` is not equal to `$value`.